# How to save cart in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and i'm trying to make a simple ecommerce where the user is able to add items to cart, view them and make a checkout.

So i have 3 components, the products list, cart and checkout and a cart service which manage all cart operations like adding items, removing and calculating the cart total.

I was wondering which would be the best solution to save the cart when the user closes the browser and reopen it as initially the user orders will be managed anonymously so without any registrations.

Is still the best solution to use localstorage and to use cookies when there will be a registration?

Comment: how about sessionstorage?

Comment: If I were you, I would probably use a mix of using cookies (per browser cookies) and storing the cart in the account information if they were signed in - eg. an accounts database with username, password, email and usual stuff with an extra column, cart, which can store an array of all the items in their cart (or json, yaml whatever)

Comment: SessionStorage is not persisted, I would either use LocalStorage or If you have a server app, I would store the cart state to a database.

Comment: `LocalStorage` is good option for your task but better to return it from service. Syncing data between DB and localStorage can create bad user experience sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

any data saved on client may change or delete by the user ,the best option is to store the data on database at the service as temporary and get the value later when the app launch again or it's open in different browser.

> localStorge will be a grate place over sessionStorgae because data in
> localStorage doesn't expire

example cart data service with localStorge [**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-data-sharing-service-local-storage?file=src/app/selected-product.service.ts)

sessionStorage will clear when the page session ends.

> A page session lasts as long as the browser is open, and survives
> over page reloads and restores

[sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Comment: going for localStorage as it seems to be the best solution and lazyest one while the registration/login part is not ready, awesome example, i was using the BehaviorSubject to get count of cart items is it better to use get?

Comment: the example is just a demo and the get property is very wrong because it will run in every change detection so try any method will be much better